# ROS IMU services, client and server node templates

Tags: ros, imu

I would like to create IMU ROS services. I have a Server(in my case is a microcontroller ESC32) that can obtain IMU reading and should pass to the Client (in my case is Raspberry PI 4B) the IMU data when requested for further processing.So I just need to pass the raw IMU data. I would like to start with some ros services template for the IMU server and client node. This is my .srv file

```
float64 x_orient_in
float64 y_orient_in
float64 z_orient_in
float64 w_orient_in
float64 x_veloc_in
float64 y_veloc_in
float64 z_veloc_in
float64 x_accel_in
float64 y_accel_in
float64 z_accel_in
---
float64 x_orient_out
float64 y_orient_out
float64 z_orient_out
float64 w_orient_out
float64 x_veloc_out
float64 y_veloc_out
float64 z_veloc_out
float64 x_accel_out
float64 y_accel_out
float64 z_accel_out
bool success
```

This is my server cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>
#include "ros_services/ImuValue.h"

bool get_val(ros_services::ImuValue::Request  &req, ros_services::ImuValue::Response &res)
{
    
    ROS_INFO("sending back response");
    res.x_orient_out= req.x_orient_in;
    res.y_orient_out= req.y_orient_in;
    res.z_orient_out= req.z_orient_in;
    res.w_orient_out= req.w_orient_in;
    res.x_veloc_out= req.x_veloc_in;
    res.y_veloc_out= req.y_veloc_in;
    res.z_veloc_out= req.z_veloc_in;
    res.x_accel_out= req.x_accel_in;
    res.x_accel_out= req.x_accel_in;
    res.x_accel_out= req.x_accel_in;
    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "imu_status_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("imu_status_server", get_val);
  ROS_INFO("Starting server...");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

And my IMU ros topic is this

```
header: 
  seq: 45672
  stamp: 
    secs: 956
    nsecs: 962000000
  frame_id: "thrbot/imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0697171053094
  y: 0.00825242210747
  z: 0.920964387685
  w: -0.383270164991
orientation_covariance: [0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.00156996015527
  y: 0.0263644782572
  z: -0.0617661883137
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 1.32039048367
  y: -0.376341478938
  z: 9.70643773249
linear_acceleration_covariance: [1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05]
```

Comment: You say service, but do you actually mean topic? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean ros services not topics. As the IMU data is not required to have it continuously. So the Server (ESC32) pass the IMU data to the PI (Client ) for processing only by request, so ROS SERVICES is a best solution for me

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: So far I tried to create ros service passing Images.

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily suggest checking out the [ros wiki tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29). They have a lot of info that can also save you some time. That being said, you would just set it up like any other service call. You will probably also have to create your own message that might look something like this:

```
float64 x_accel
float64 y_accel
float64 z_accel
---
bool success
```

Then you just need a server node to handling incoming requests like this:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "your_service/service_file.h"

bool get_val(your_service::service_file::Request  &req,
         your_service::service_file::Response &res)
{
  res.x_accel = get_accel_x(); //Defined somewhere else by you
  res.y_accel = get_accel_y(); //Defined somewhere else by you
  res.z_accel = get_accel_z(); //Defined somewhere else by you
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "imu_status_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("imu_status_server", add);
  ROS_INFO("Starting server...");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

Finally, the client can make calls to the server like this

```
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts>("imu_status_server");
your_service::service_file srv;
client.call(srv);
std::cout << "Got accel x: " << srv.response.x_accel << std::endl;
```

Comment: sorry one question. x_accel, y_accel, z_accel are defined in the .srv file with float64 x_accel, float64 y_accel, float64 z_accel. Same for x,y,z,w orientation and x,y,z angular velocity? Correct?

Comment: I add the ROS IMU topic in the question. So taking into account that what would be the .msg and .srv files?

Comment: Orientation and angular velocity should also be a gloat64 in your srv file. For the above example that’s the only custom msg/srv file needed. You don’t need a custom message just to get imu data via a srv call.

Comment: so my srv file is float64 x_orient
float64 y_orient
float64 z_orient
float64 w_orient
float64 x_veloc
float64 y_veloc
float64 z_veloc
float64 x_accel
float64 y_accel
float64 z_accel
---
bool success

Comment: I add my service cpp file in the question. Is that right now?

Comment: That looks like it should be correct to me.

Comment: so in this way I can just pass the IMU data from the server to the client, right?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the desired fields via a service call to the client this way.

Comment: ok. Sorry last thing , can I pass also the orientation_covariance, angular_velocity_covariance and the linear_acceleration_covariance?

Comment: Sure. ROS service files use msg types as fields. This means you can also add `float64[9] somethings_covariance` to your srv file for covariance just fine.

Comment: hi. I got error ros_services::ImuValue::Response {aka struct ros_services::ImuValueResponse_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘x_orient’

Comment: That error is going to be because `x_orient` isn't actually a field that was added to your `srv` file

Comment: yes yes. fix it. Sorry the last question. Can I have more services in one package? Like IMU service file IMU.srv then Sonar.srv then Camera.srv in srv folder and corresponr server and client nodes in srs folder? Or I need separate srv folder for each services?

Comment: so in CMakeLists.txt file I add this line add_service_files(
 FILES
 ImuValue.srv
 SonarValue.srv
) but still got error  fatal error: ros_services/SonarValue.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ros_services/SonarValue.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Any help?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one in each package. Make sure you're running `catkin_make clean` as sometimes stale builds make it into `devel`

Comment: ok. When run the rosrun ros_services ImuClient 
Got orient x: 0
Got orient y: 0
Got orient z: 0
Got orient w: 0

Comment: all Imu values are 0. How come?

Comment: I update the latest code in the question. But still the Client responce values are all zero

Comment: Can't say without seeing all of the code. I'd assume the code isn't caching imu values to put into the response object correctly. This is fairly off topic from the original question so further comments should probably be their own question.

Comment: so I should open a new question and add the server and client code?

Comment: I think so. SO best practices is to not have extended discussion in comments; especially if off topic from the original question.

Comment: ok. I created a new topic and includes the .srv file, server and client node. Pls check. Thanks